# What are the syscalls for drawing graphics on the screen in Linux?

Tags: linux, graphics, system-calls

I was searching for a syscall that would draw a pixel on a given coordinate on the screen on something similar. But I couldn't find any such syscalls in [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/constants/syscalls.md) site.

I came to know that OS interacts with monitors using graphic drivers. But these drivers may be different on different machines. So is there a common native API provided by linux for handling these?

Much like how there are syscalls for opening, closing, reading, writing to files. Even though underlying file systems maybe different, these syscalls provide an abstract API for user programs to simplify things. I was searching something similar for drawing onto the screen.

Comment: I don't think so. I think most applications use the X Window System or higher-level libraries, they don't access the screen directly.

Comment: @Barmar X Window is for Windows??

Comment: No, it's for Unix.

Comment: No, X Windows is the (used to be) the underlying abstraction layer for graphical applications on Linux.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System. An alternative would be to use the framebuffer device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically a user is running a display server and window system which organizes the screen into windows which applications draw to individually using the API provided by that system. The details will depend on the architecture of this system.

The traditional window system on Linux is the [X window system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) and the more modern [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)) display server/protocol is also in common use. For example X has commands to instruct the X server to draw primitives to the screen.

If no such system is in use, you can directly draw to a display either via a framebuffer device or using the [DRM API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager). Both are not accessed by special syscalls, but instead by using normal file syscalls like `open`, `read`, `write`, etc., but also `ioctl`, on special device files in `/dev`, e.g. `/dev/dri/card0` for DRM to the first graphics card or `/dev/fb0` for the first framebuffer device. DRM is also used for applications to render directly to the screen or a buffer when under a display server or window system as above.

In any case DRM is usually not used directly to draw e.g. pixels to the screen. It still is specific to the graphics card. Typically a library like [Mesa3D](https://mesa3d.org/) is used to translate the specific details into a common API like OpenGL or Vulkan for applications to use.

Comment: Surprisingly, both `/dev/dri` and `/dev/fb0` does not exist in my system. (PS: I am using Ubuntu inside WSL).

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB WSL seems to be providing a Wayland server directly, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wslg-architecture/.

Comment: Then, if I am writing a program on Linux, there is no definite cross-platform way to draw on screen? I must always know about target machine?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB If you write an application you usually use a GUI toolkit like GTK, Qt or many others or a graphics/multimedia library like SDL, SFML or many others. They typically support both acting as X client and as Wayland client (and maybe others) and offer a unified way of creating windows and drawing to them. Which one you choose is a matter of taste. Linux distributions usually have all of them in their repositories and if a user doesn't have them available you can also ship these libraries with your application.

Comment: But, how do those applications work in all devices? Do they check which server is running in each machine, and accordingly call corresponding functions?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Yes, there are environment variables set when a user is running their desktop under Wayland or X11 based on which they can decide which to use. For example X11 uses `DISPLAY`. They also typically add their own environment variables to override this decision making. Both Wayland and X11 typically work by having the server open file sockets to which clients can write and read to communicate with the server and the location of these sockets is either given by an environment variable or some default path. For example on my system the X server has a socket at `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Although, in contrast to Wayland, X11 is actually a network-transparent protocol and it is possible to communicate with the X server and draw to the screen over network protocols as well, e.g. TCP. (However this doesn't allow for direct rendering via DRM, which makes this unsuitable for anything that requires efficient drawing.)